# why Matlab parfeval function slower than normal?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

When I call function normally, execution time is much faster than parfeval.

```
tic
f = parfeval(@magic,1,10000);
value = fetchOutputs(f);
toc
Elapsed time is 2.244390 seconds.
```

magic function works on parfeval with 2.24 seconds.

```
tic
magic(10000);
toc
Elapsed time is 0.592743 seconds.
```

But when i call normally, it works fastly. What is the reason of this and How to speed up parfeval function?

Comment: By default, `parfeval` and other Parallel Toolbox functionality uses multiple processes and message passing between them for parallelism. This involves a large overhead. Thread-based parallelism has less overhead. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parpool.html and here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is some overhead that needs to be considered when setting up threads (which `parfeval` does). This is the main reason for the time discrepancy.

When using any kind of parallel processing you have to first determine if the process runs long enough that the overhead from spawning the processes is negligible. In this case, it isn't.

Testing a longer run case:

```
tic
test(1E10)
toc

tic
f = parfeval(@test, 1, 1E10)
value = fetchOutputs(f);
toc

function x = test(n)
  x = 1;
  for i = 1:n
    x = x * 1;
  end
end
```

Which gives the time (on my computer) `5.51` and `5.49` seconds.